# In Blender, simply mix two image layers like in Gimp

Tags: animation, image

In Gimp I've got two layers with identically images with text in middle grey in the foreground on a black background. The lower layers's mode is set to 'normal' while the higher one's is set to 'addition'.

Moving one layer against the other leads to the effect, that those image parts alter to light grey where the middle greys overlap.

[image: moved image on two layers]

How can I achieve this behaviour in Blender?

Comment: are you looking for a material that uses your two images or do you want overlapping meshes to produce the same result? For the first one use an Add Shader

Comment: Whether I use textures or overlapping meshes, I don't care. It is important that I can animate the images separately to create "living" mixes.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ok it looks like it's not what you're looking for, you want 2 different planes and I give a solution for one plane:

You could simply mix your 2 pictures in a *Color* > *MixRGB* node (set on *Mix*):

[image]

Comment: I'd like to put my images each on a plane to later move them separately. Where did you put your images on?

Comment: oh ok I thought you wanted both your pictures to be mixed on the same plane. In that case you need another material...